# Asterisk.NET: How to hook event when human lifts up the phone?

Tags: c#, voip, asterisk

I will add action right in moment, when human lifts up the phone (e.g.: open `Notepad`). Which `event` should I use? I tried a lot of `events` from `ManagerConnection` but could not find solution.

**EDIT:** I will do same functionality like on screenshot (make something, when human lifts up the phone). ADAT programm has this functionality and will have too.

[image]

**EDIT 2:** I found solution. Sample code:

Subscribe to event

```
managerConnection.NewState += new NewStateEventHandler(Monitoring_NewState);

    private void Monitoring_NewState(object sender, NewStateEvent e)
    {
        string state = e.State;
        string callerID = e.CallerId;
        if ((state == "Ringing") | (e.ChannelState == "5"))
        {
            String connectedLineNum;
            String connectedLineName;

            Dictionary<String, String> attributes = e.Attributes;

            attributes.TryGetValue("connectedlinenum", out connectedLineNum);
            attributes.TryGetValue("connectedlinename", out connectedLineName);
            // "callerID" - called phone number
            // "connectedLineNum" - calling phone number

            // CallIn. Incoming call
        }
        else if ((state == "Ring") | (e.ChannelState == "4"))
        {
            // CallOut. Outcoming call
        }
        else if ((state == "Up") | (e.ChannelState == "6"))
        {
            String connectedLineNum;
            String connectedLineName;


            Dictionary<String, String> attributes = e.Attributes;

            attributes.TryGetValue("connectedlinenum", out connectedLineNum);
            attributes.TryGetValue("connectedlinename", out connectedLineName);
            // "callerID" - called phone number
            // "connectedLineNum" - calling phone number

            // human lifted up the phone right now
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to clarify: Do you want it when someone *picks up* the phone? Or when someone *answers* the phone?  There's a huge difference there.

Comment: When someone picks up the phone. Thank's, I already found necessary event and used .NET Reflector programm for reverse engineering programm from screenshot :)

Comment: I'm glad you found it - you should add an answer explaining how to do it so that anyone else with the same problem can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

When human lift up phone in case of voip nothing happens. Voip/sip is digital network, as result phone(client) not distrub server if nothing happens(user not entered phone number). Some clients with auto-dial # on lift up exist(used in calling card public phone installation), but most of phones just not inform server(asterisk) about that event. As result you can't get this event in your program.